# Is it possible to call an overloaded function from overwriting function in Julia?

Tags: julia, abstract, overloading

The problem is the following:

I have an abstract type `MyAbstract` and derived composite types `MyType1` and `MyType2`:

```
abstract type MyAbstract end

struct MyType1 <: MyAbstract
    somestuff
end

struct MyType2 <: MyAbstract
    someotherstuff
end
```

I want to specify some general behaviour for objects of type `MyAbstract`, so I have a function

```
function dosth(x::MyAbstract)
    println(1) # instead of something useful
end
```

This general behaviour suffices for `MyType1` but when `dosth` is called with an argument of type `MyType2`, I want some additional things to happen that are specific for `MyType2` and, of course, I want to reuse the existing code, so I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
function dosth(x::MyType2)
    dosth(x::MyAbstract)
    println(2)
end

x = MyType2("")
dosth(x) # StackOverflowError
```

This means Julia did not recognize my attempt to treat `x` like its "supertype" for some time.

Is it possible to call an overloaded function from the overwriting function in Julia? How can I elegantly solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`invoke` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.invoke)

```
function dosth(x::MyType2)
    invoke(dosth, Tuple{MyAbstract}, x)
    println(2)
end
```

With the same setup, this gives the follow output instead of a stack overflow:

```
julia> dosth(x)
1
2
```

There's a currently internal and experimental macro version of `invoke` which can be called like this:

```
function dosth(x::MyType2)
    Base.@invoke dosth(x::MyAbstract)
    println(2)
end
```

This makes the calling syntax quite close to what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I read into the discussion you linked. The name `@callsuper` would express the idea of what I want to do very well.

Comment: Thanks – that's helpful feedback. I think that's the best name so far too.